# Extended Traceroute on ASA 5550

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

My co-worker and I are curious if you can use the traceroute [IP Address] source [interface name] successfully on the Cisco ASA 55** series. We are running on 8.4(2).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASA does not allow to specify outgoing interface/IP for traceroute command, unfortunately.

To check if packets are running thru ASA correctly you can use **packet-tracer** command:

```
packet-tracer input <input_interface> <proto> <source_addr_or_fqdn> <port> <dest_addr_or_fqdn> <port> <detailed>
```

Comment: packet-tracer may result in false positive, when routing is done incorrectly. **capture** may be used as well.